# Problem with IF command in comment.html.twig

Tags: 8, comments

I create a "select" field (field_points) in comment section that users rating my content and in "manage display" I set "key" for my field format.

```
5|Excellent
4|Good
3|No Idea
2|Bad
1|Very Bad
```

Now I use this code in comment.html.twig:

```
{% if content.field_points == 5 %}
   *****
{% elseif content.field_points == 4 %}
    ****
{% elseif content.field_points == 3 %}
    ***
{% elseif content.field_points == 2 %}
    **
{% elseif content.field_points == 1 %}
    *
{% endif %}
```

When I use this code nothing is displayed But when I use {{ content.field_points }} , print for example 5 ( 5 is field key ).

How can I fix this problem in drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the comment entity to get the raw field value instead:

```
{% if comment.field_points.value == 5 %}
   *****
{% elseif comment.field_points.value == 4 %}
   ****

...

{% endif %}
```

This doesn't work with `{{ content }}`, because it contains a build array to render the fields.

Comment: Thanks but when I use {% if comment.field_points.value == 5 %} just show last comment rating and others not print. And when I use {% if comment.field_points == 5 %} all comment just show * in rating section

Comment: This is only an example how to use the field value, I didn't code the complete logic.